# MicroSoft bot Framework CardAction Buttons were not looking proper in WebChat window

Tags: botframework

I am working on a Chatbot using **MicroSoft Bot Framework** and planning to Embed the same with my website as WebChat.
We have used CardActions as attachment. These were getting displayed properly in Bot Emulator, but not looking proper(please see example buttons below) in **WebChat** window.

*(Button Text 1) Button Value 1
(Button Text 2) Button Value 2
(Button Text 3) Button Value 3*

Is this the expected behaviour? How can we have proper buttons in **WebChat** as in Facebook / Skype Bots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons are not supported by the *Web Chat* channel at this moment. That is true not for cards only, but for prompts as well. I believe, the Bot Framework team has this feature in their backlog. Meanwhile, if this is critical for your project, please consider to implement your own web chat control using the [Direct Line API](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline/).

Comment: We do intend to extend the capabilities of the WebChat control, but for now Eugene is right, buttons won't render as controls in the UI.

Comment: Update on this: the new version of the WebChat is available and now it supports cards. Open source too: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat